# Background noise reduction решение

Tags: python, аудио, машинное-обучение

Мне нужно сделать `background noise reduction / remove` на Python или через `open source API`.

Comment: всмысле нужно сделать за вас? безвозмездно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [noisereduce](https://pypi.org/project/noisereduce/):

```
import noisereduce as nr
# load data
rate, data = wavfile.read("mywav.wav")
# select section of data that is noise
noisy_part = data[10000:15000]
# perform noise reduction
reduced_noise = nr.reduce_noise(audio_clip=data, noise_clip=noisy_part, verbose=True)
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ! А noisereduce юзает ffmpeg? Мне нужно сначала переделать mp3 в wav с помощью ffmpeg, или можно как то изменить wavfile.read?